# validity of paranthesized string parallel processing

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, parallel-processing, stack

**Ques1**
 You are given a string containing just the characters `'(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']'`, for example, `"[{()}]"`, you need to write a function which will check validity of such an input string.

I am able to do it using stacks.

**Ques2**
Do it using multiple processors at the same time .

How can it be done ?

According to me , it can't be done because :
Let us assume we have 3 processors and input string is :`([{([])}])` and divide to the 3 processors as :
1st :`([{`
2nd :`([]`
3rd :`)}])`
Now applying the procedure , we get FALSE from all the 3 processors , therefore it can't be solved by parallel processing .
`Is it right or parallel processing means something else ?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to have the first thread start at the beginning of the string and use the stack to process the first half of the string. A second thread starts at the end of the string and processes the second half of the string *in reverse*.

When both threads have completed that first phase, then the first thread treats the second thread's stack as the continuation of the string.

So, for example, you have:

```
[({(())}[])]
```

thread 1 gets `[({(()`, and thread 2 gets `)}[])]`

They each finish thier processing, resulting in these two stacks (left is top of stack):

```
`({([`  `)})]`
```

Then thread 1 can turn thread 2's stack into a string (or treat the stack as a string, popping one character at a time), and continue its processing.

Come to think of it, when the two threads are done processing their half of the string, the two stacks must be the same length, and they are mirrors of each other. The first thread's stack will contain only opening delimiters (i.e. '(', '[', or '{'), and the second thread's stack will contain only closing delimiters. So after both threads are finished with their half of the processing, the final part is simply:

```
while (stack1.Count > 0 && stack2.Count > 0)
{
    left = stack1.Pop();
    right = stack2.Pop();
    if (!delimiters_match(left, right))
    {
        // error!
    }
}
```

Note that at any time during the processing, it's possible for either thread to detect an error. For example, given:

```
([){})[)
```

The first thread knows that an error occurred in the third character because you can't have `)` immediately follow `[`. Similarly, the second thread knows that there's an error with the `[` (next to last character), because you can't have `[` immediately before `)`.

But some errors can only be detected during the second phase. For example:

```
({[}])
```

The left and right substrings are valid, but when combined they're not.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the example you have chosen can't be solved in parallel in the way you set about it.

Consider instead a test expression of, say, 200000 characters.  Split that over 2 processors (let's keep things simple).  Each processor:

1. Scans its sub-string for any occurrences of `[]`,`{}` or `()`, that is of two consecutive symbols which form a valid string.  When it finds such an occurrence it simply deletes it.
2. Repeat step 1 until no more changes are made to the substring.
3. Recombine the substrings and have 1 processor repeat step 1 until nothing more changes.

I expect that someone with more time than I have right now could construct examples which are so long that recursive splitting across 2, 4, 8, ... processors, or across 3, 6, 9,... would be worthwhile.   I expect it's also possible to construct examples which show no speed up, in fact the opposite, if split across processors.